# The problem with using #include <experimental/propagate_const> and MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, file-not-found, c++-experimental

I have run into a problem with including  into my project, in spite of the fact that I have set the language of the project to "ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest)" in "MSVS 2017". Any help will be appreciated.

It is worth mentioning that it does not happen when I use another compilers including GCC and Clang.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>     <======= the problem is here

class widget {
    class impl;
    std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<impl>> pImpl;
public:

};
```

Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'experimental/propagate_const': No such file or directory

Comment: Microsoft hasn't implemented that **experimental** header yet. I checked my current installation of MSVC 2019 version 16.1.5 and it's also not implemented there.

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/propagate_const --- has anybody ported this to MSVC, yet   ... Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I just found a Visual Studio implementation in [github](https://github.com/jbcoe/propagate_const)

Comment: VS 2022 17.5 **still** doesn't have this :(